# How to make it different interval bxslider per image and also with time interval use localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slider, bxslider

i want to make slider use bxslider so that the interval is different per image and also time interval use localstorage, but my code seems to be wrong.

what i want is first image interval 1s and then second image interval 5s, etc so per image the interval is different and time interval use localstorage

this is my code  `jsfiddle.net/noval_id/4qbs5jw0/`

Comment: [Everthing works perfectly fine](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZKpXj) But your code doesn't works because you have to load [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) before using any jquery plugins.

Comment: thanks for answer, but the slider not yet running by the interval.. please check my code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/noval_id/4qbs5jw0/

Comment: Because jquery is not being loaded correctly and your CDN's don't work, they show a 404, See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgdyamp4/1/) and notice how i load jquery and your cdns

Comment: okay after i include the jquery means what I have to do so that per image interval is different like this  `var ImagePauses = [1000,3000,6000,9000,12000,15000];` and use time localstorage so first image interval is 1000, then second image interval is 3000,etc  because the slider still not yet different interval , this my code in fiddle when already add jquery http://jsfiddle.net/9dcn1Lsp/

Comment: I've just added `modifyDelay` on the `slideAfter` event with the index, it is now working. See this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeaMwq)

Comment: yes nice, thanks brother :)

Comment: Visitors don't read comments but see accepted answers, if this question proved helpful for someone in future, please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: of course sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Your weren't getting multiple delays because you weren't running your function again, if you want different delay values, you have to run it again and again for the different delay values you stored in the array.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
var startIndex = localStorage.getItem("currentIndex");

if (startIndex == null)
  startIndex = 0;

var ImagePauses = [1000,30000,2000,9000,12000,15000];
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
modifyDelay(0)

function modifyDelay(startSlide){
    slider.reloadSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        infiniteLoop: true,
        auto: true,
        autoStart: true,
        autoDirection: 'next',
        autoHover: true,
        pause: ImagePauses[startSlide],
        autoControls: false,
        pager: true,
        pagerType: 'full',
        controls: true,
        captions: true,
        speed: 500,
        startSlide: startSlide,
        onSlideAfter: function($el,oldIndex, newIndex){
            modifyDelay(newIndex) // here run it again with new index
            save($el, oldIndex, newIndex)
        } 
    });
}
});
function save($el, oldIndex, newIndex) {
  localStorage.setItem("currentIndex", newIndex);
}
```

Also wrap your jquery code in `$(document).ready` function.